# Jmeter - Constant throughput timer - Requests for per second

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2

Is there any function in JMeter using groovy, beanshell to give Target throughput in seconds? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want convert requests per minute into requests per second you need to multiply the value by 60.

The relevant [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) would be something like:

```
${__groovy(target_throughput_in_requests_per_second * 60,)}
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Also be informed that:

- Constant Throughput Timer is precise enough **on minute level** so you might need to adjust your ramp-up period or consider using [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) instead
- Constant Throughput Timer can only pause the threads to limit JMeter's requests execution rate to the given value so make sure to supply sufficient amount in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)